# Hibernate release bundle and pom.xml: setting development environment

Tags: java, hibernate, maven-2

I am new to Hibernate 3 and I don't understand the difference between 
1) *http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate3/ 
and 
2) *https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/
when it comes to compiling Hibernate tutorial files. 
I am following Hibernate tutorial from *http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/quickstart/en-US/html_single/ 
As I understand there is no setup.exe for Hibernate 3. I assume that instead of having setup.exe I need to set classpaths to get my Hibernate 3 installed.
I have downloaded release of Hibernate from the list at *http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate3/. It's more than 140 MB. After having unzipped this 140 MB file I didn't set any classpaths. 
 I downloaded tutorial code from *http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/quickstart/en-US/html_single/files/hibernate-tutorials.zip, unzipped it and edited pom.xml in this way that this tutorial would use two repositories like 
1) *http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/
and
2) *https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/
Then I typed mvn compile and build was succesful!
How is it possible that this build was succesful? I didn't set any classpaths which means that Hibernate 3 (that 140 MB file) was not included in my project's classpath. Moreover I don't understand what means to include in my project's classpath? Does it mean that under Windows XP I should set environment variables like:
1) path/to/hibernate3.jar
2) path/to/lib/required/
3) path/to/lib/jpa/
When I added these three paths to environment variables it didn't change anything - mvn compile worked the same way as before. Did I set this classpath in the wrong way?
In my point of view it seems to me that it is not necessary to download Hibernate 3 (140 MB) at all and all the files that were necessary to build this hibernate application (tutorial file) successfully were downloaded from repositories.
What do I misunderstand?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to read up on how Maven works. There is an excellent free PDF called [Better Builds with Maven](http://repo.exist.com/dist/maestro/1.7.0/BetterBuildsWithMaven.pdf) that will explain it all in some detail, however here is a quick overview to help you along.

**Maven is a build system**

So it manages how to build your project. This comes from the configuration details you put in the pom.xml. You defined dependencies and Maven knows how to find them as a result either you configuring those locations, or Maven relying on it's own default locations. (This is where the http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ is coming from).

Maven builds in defined phases, with each phase relying on the one before it. In order these are (simplified for easy presentation):

1. Clean - wipe out any previous compilation work (usually in "target") and start afresh
2. Copy resources - copy everything under src/main/resources to target/classes
3. Compile - compile everything under src/main/java to target/classes
4. Test - run the tests under src/test/java (using src/test/resources if required)
5. Package - build the target artifact (JAR, WAR, EAR etc)
6. Install - put the artifact into the local repository (to share with other local projects)
7. Deploy - put the artifact into the team repository (to share with everyone else)

From the above, it should be clear that specifying Hibernate3 as a dependency in your Maven pom.xml will instruct Maven to go off and look in your local repository for the necessary JAR files that make up Hibernate. If it can't find them there it'll look in the team repository (if mentioned in your .m2/settings.xml file). If not there then it'll download them from Maven central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/).

Maven uses the concept of transitive dependencies meaning that your project depends on Hibernate, but Hibernate depends on CGLIB which in turn depends on, say, ANTLR or something. You don't have to think about that, Maven takes care of bringing in all the relevant JARs you need to make your project work.